# Cannot get sound in Windows 7 - No audio devices are installed

Tags: windows-7, drivers, audio

Just installed Windows 7. After install everything was working fine until i noticed that i had no sound.

It is a AMD Athlon x64 Dual

Sound works in XP, has these sound drivers

```
  Yamaha DS1 WDM
  HD Audio Render
```

I tried finding the above drivers, but no luck.

Update: System info:

```
  Board: ASUSTeK Computer INC. A8R-MVP Rev 1.xx
  Sound Card Model: LW-SC4C
  Windows Version: Windows 7 Ultimate (x64)
```

Comment: Assuming the sound is on-board the motherboard, what kind of motherboard (make/model)?

Comment: Board is: ASUSTeK Computer INC. A8R-MVP Rev 1.xx

Answer (score 1):

You can troubleshoot the problem by booting to an Ubuntu Live DVD (or similar), to determine if it is a hardware or software issue.

If the audio hardware has failed, or you do not want to troubleshoot your Windows installation any further, an easy solution is to purchase a very inexpensive USB sound device. They look just like a USB thumb drive and will plug into a USB port on the back plane of your computer where it will essentially be a replacement sound card. (For example, Deal Extreme has them for less than $4 including shipping)

I found this work-around to be very convenient and flexible solution rather than wasting my time trying to fix the problem.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, HD Audio Render is a generic driver type for an HD audio card. You should be able to follow [these instructions](http://www.technospot.net/blogs/how-to-find-your-hardware-device-vendor/) to find out the manufacturer and model of your audio card and then find the appropriate drivers. If you find the vendor & device string and need help finding the driver, you can always edit your original question or leave a comment on this answer. Cheers!

Comment: Model no is: LW-SC4C , can not find any information on PCIVendor

Answer (score 0):

it happens when windows enables wrong output to sound , I had this problem too. you shoud do this procedure ,

1)  Open Control Panel (All items view)and double click the Sound icon.

[image]

2)  In the Sound window you will notice the Speakers and other audio devices connected under Playback tab.

[image]

3)  Now click on Speakers and then click Properties button as highlighted above.

4)  In the Speaker Properties dialog box select Use this device to enable Speakers in the Device usage dropdown list at the bottom.

[image]

5) Click Apply and then OK button

Answer (score 0):

There has been the same issue in my Windows 10 laptop and reason for which was quite difficult to find out. Updating the driver, reinstalling it also did not solve the issue. But it was actually [Audio Renderer Error](https://www.internettablettalk.com/audio-renderer-error/) that occurred in my device.

Comment: Can you copy the steps from the link? That way if the link is no longer active, you answer will still be valid